# React. redux-ORM. Не обновляется state после добавления данных

Tags: reactjs, redux, orm

2 дня не могу решить проблему, всё что можно перепробовал.

Использую react, redux-toolkit и redux-orm. При записи полученых значений в редьюсер orm модели, стейт не обновляется. Подробнее:

Есть простая модель:

```
//Файл Product.js

import { Model, many, attr, fk } from "redux-orm";

export class Product extends Model {
  static modelName = "Product";

  static reducer(action, Product, session) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_PRODUCT': {
        Product.create(action.payload)
        break
      }
    }
  }

}

Product.fields = {
  id: attr(),
  name: attr(),
  category_id: fk({
    to: "Category",
    as: "category",
    relatedName: "products",
  }),
};
```

Зарегестрировал её в ORM и далее в store

После, в компонентах, делаю стандартный `dispatch` с type 'ADD_PRODUCT' и payload соответствующий объявленной модели и вижу, что попадаю в редьюсер, все типы и значения данных соответствуют, всё идёт как должно.

Но в последствии при дальнейшем получении стейта

```
const state = useSelector(state => state);
```

Получаю стейт с собранным правильно orm редьюсером, но с пустым объектом Product.

Самое интересное: запрашивая `console.log(state)` я получаю пустой стейт, но если я не обновляя страницу, подправлю код и сработает самостоятельное обновление страницы React, то в консоль получаю заполненный как надо стейт.

Складывается ощущение, что ORM просто не возвращает новую версию стейта, а при автообновление страницы после правки кода, в консоль выводится уже обновленный стейт.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с чем то подобным? Хоть какие то мысли?

Comment: Обнаружил, что на вход в функцию редьюсера модели, приходит session со значением session.withMutations= false. Если в ручную меняю на true, то получаю ошибки о мутации стейта, но в консоли, в стейте, начали появляться объекты. Думаю, что ответ где то здесь.

Comment: Так же обнаружил, что если внутри других подобных приведенному выше редьюсеру, вывести console.log(session), то внутри session можно найти state с уже добавленными данными и все там корректно. Но вот куда после, эта сессия девается - не понятно

Comment: Я попробовал отстранено, без API запросов, прослоек приложения и излишних функций сделать dispatch фиксированного объекта и в таком случае позже, при запросе я получил нужный мне стейт с добавленным объектом. Кажется дело в API

Comment: Проблема в sync / async. Решение будет добавлено сегодня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в банальном sync / async.
Решением стало `Promise.all`

В своём приложении я делал компонент обёртку который должен был сначала получить все данные, а уже после отрисовывать контентную часть. Т.е. нужно было дождаться разрешения всех промисов. Вот что получилось:

```
  useEffect(() => {

Promise.all([
  getProducts(),         //Запрос к серверу
  getCover(),         //Запрос к серверу
  getCategories(),         //Запрос к серверу
  getProductVariations(),         //Запрос к серверу
  getProductVariationProp(),         //Запрос к серверу
  getProductVariationPropListValues(),          //Запрос к серверу
  getProductVariationPropValue(),         //Запрос к серверу
]).then((result) => 
        createObjects(dispatch, result, dataLoading));
//dataLoading при вызове установит dataIsLoad в true
}, []);

  return dataIsLoad ? <>{children}</> : <div>LOADING...</div>;
```

Внутри функции `createObjects` мы просто перебираем массив значений который вернул `Promise.all`, выполняем нужные диспатчи, а в конце вызываем `dataLoading` благодоря чему отрисывываем дочерние компоненты с уже сформированным стейтом в который уже добавлены все необходимые объекты,а  так же составлена таблица redux-ORM

Код функции createObjects

```
export const createObjects = (
  dispatch,
  array,
  dataLoading
) => {
  const subsequence = [
    "ADD_PRODUCT",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_COVER",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_VARIATION",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_VARIATION_PROPERTY",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_VARIATION_PROP_LIST_VALUES",
    "ADD_PRODUCT_VARIATION_PROPERTY_VALUE",
  ];

  array.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.forEach((item) => {
      dispatch({ type: subsequence[index], payload: item });
    });
  });

  dispatch(dataLoading());
};
```

Так что вопрос не столько про redux-ORM, сколько про асинхронность